# How to use JSX spread attributes to pass arbitrary props to my controlled component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In a controlled component, how do I pass arbitrary props to the render function?  I think I need to make use of a constructor but I am getting "props is not defined" and other errors.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

import styles from './Styles';

export default class MyView extends React.Component {

  constructor(????) {
    // What do I do so I can use {...props} in the render function below?
  }

  render() { 
    return (
      <View style={styles.wrap} {...props}>
        <View style={styles.main}>
          {this.props.children}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

I want to be able to do...

```
<MyView arbitraryprop="123" />
```

...and have arbitraryprop get passed to MyView::render().

Comment: May I add that React should be imported as `import React from 'react'`, as you don't need anything else in the present example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default constructor of `<Component>` does already initialize `this.props`. If the only thing you are doing in your component's constructor is to initialize your props you can leave the constructor out completely. Otherwise you have to call the super constructor with the props:

```js
constructor(props) {
    // call the super constructor
    super(props);

    // do your additional initialization, e.g. set initial state
}
```

Also your example can't work properly as you did not initialize the local variable `props` inside your `render()` function. It has to look something like this:

```
render() { 
    const {children, ...props} = this.props;

    return (
      <View style={styles.wrap} {...props}>
        <View style={styles.main}>
          {children}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must use the proper scope when referencing props. In other words, this is a class so `props` isn't defined in the render function, but `this.props` is. Add `this.` to the beginning and it will work. (e.g. `{...this.props}`

Answer (score 2):

```
<View style={styles.wrap} {...this.props}>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I don't even need the constructor.  At least, not for present purposes.